# Laravel - AppServiceProvider is not called

Tags: laravel

I tried to bind some services in the Laravel AppServiceProvider, but the services weren't bound. I think, that the AppServiceProvider was not even called. Actually, I made a new one and it works.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong? Or was the AppServiceProvider not called?

Comment: If the service provider is registered in `config/app.php` it should be called. To say more I need to see your code

Comment: This provider is in Laravel as default provider, i mean, that this provider is not mine, i just tried to add some more binds into it.

Comment: I'm well aware of that.

Comment: I did not manipulate with this provider, so is there something, what i should do?

Comment: First, check if its really not called (add `dd('test')` in the `register` method). Second, add your code to the question.

Comment: Oh, i just tried to run artisan command "clear-compiled" and it works, i am a little bit confused, what was the real problem?

Comment: Ahh. I know what the problem was... I'll write an answer later (I'm on my phone at the moment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel **pre-compiles** certain classes that are used on basically every request. This serves the purpose of performance optimization. Files to compile can be specified in `config/compile.php` under `files`. The [default one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php) looks like this:

```
'files' => [
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php'),
],
```

When running `php artisan optimize` when debugging is not enabled (or with the `--force` option) Those listed files and other framework classes will be written to `storage/framework/compiled.php`.

That means if you change one of those precompiled files, changes won't be applied immediately (if `compiled.php` exists) but only after you run `php artisan optimize` again or after you run `php artisan clear-compiled` to clear the `compiled.php` file.

Of course you can also remove the `AppServiceProvider` from the list as an alternative solution.