# AppServiceProvider Not work's in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my `app.php` code where I use **AppServiceProvider**  :

```
/*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
```

And here is my **AppServiceProvider** boot function. I want to use `$a` in `pages.companyname` page. I'm trying to do this so I can use that value on every page:

```
public function boot()
    {
        //
        $a = 10;
        view()->composer('pages.companyname', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('latest', $a);
    });    
    }
```

This is my pages/companyname.blade.php page :

```
{!! $latest !!}
```

But It's showing this error

> "Undefined variable: latest "

I followed this [example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-pass-variables-to-master-template)

How can I solve this? I want to use one variable across my pages..

> N.B : Now $a is a demo variable. I will replace it by SQL query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel - AppServiceProvider is not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676365/laravel-appserviceprovider-is-not-called)

Comment: did you follow this video https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25

Comment: Thanks guys, I got my Problem in compiled.php file now worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to pass a variable into a closure, you use `use`.

```
$a = 10;
view()->composer('pages.companyname', function($view) use ($a)
{
    $view->with('latest', $a);
});
```